# Make the info box at the bottom of the screen closeable or (re)move it altogether

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When viewing questions that are closed or have an open bounty, a box is displayed at the bottom of the screen (I'm talking about the android app).

It does not only block a substantial part of my screen, it also disables me to scroll up by sliding my finger from the bottom of the screen upwards, because the sliding isn't registered when it starts above the box.

So my feature request is to make this box closeable. Or even better (re)move it completely. When reading a question I don't really care whether it's closed or not, this becomes more important when I try to answer. And the open bounty might be interesting while I'm reading the question, but not while looking at the answers. So maybe the information could be moved at the top or between the question and the answers? Then it'd scroll with the content and disappear when it's not needed.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about this... I agree that it's not the nicest interface right now but making it closeable will add in too much interactions in the tiny container it's in right now. We'll consider this when we talk about more redesigns in the app though.